# Dynamically add item to ListBox whose DataSource is bound to a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, reflection

I'm trying to create custom reusable WPF UserControl that has a listbox and a button to add a new row, just like how a DataGrid can allow users to add a new row.

This control will be bound to many different types of collections in various view models (i.e. List, ObservableCollection, etc.).

I have the UserControl with a dependency property called DataSource of type IEnumerable (it has to be IEnumerable to allow ObservableCollections, Lists, etc). I want to create a new instance of whatever object is in the underlying collection, and add it to the original collection that is bound to ItemsSource.

I have created a method that will make a new instance of an object that the collection is comprised of:

```
private object GetNewItem()
{
    if (ItemsSource == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("ItemsSource not set");

    Type itemType = null;
    foreach (Type i in ItemsSource.GetType().GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
            itemType = i.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }

    if (itemType == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Unable to get ItemsSource's Type T");

    return Activator.CreateInstance(itemType);
}
```

Now I just need to get that new object added to the original collection. Unfortunately, IEnumerable does not allow adding items, as it's not intended to be mutable.

I can detect which type of collection was originally used, i.e.:

```
if (itemsType.IsGenericType && itemsType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
```

So, I can get the type of collection, and that collection's generic type (i.e. collection was an 'ObservableCollection<>', and the generic type was 'Person'), but I cannot figure out how to cast it back... and even if I could, I couldn't add the result of GetNewItem to it as:

```
((ObservableCollection<Person>) ItemsSource).Add(object)
```

... doesn't work without casting object to 'Person'.

DataGrids are able to add a new instance of it's ItemsSource's underlying type, even though it's ItemsSource is IEnumerable, so I know it isn't impossible. I  just can't see how to make it work. I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid adds new items with help of `IEditableCollectionView` view based on ItemsSource: see [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs,3572)

so try cast ItemsSource to IEditableCollectionView and add new item without creating instance yourself.

```
var c = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource) as IEditableCollectionView;
if (c != null && c.CanAddNew)
    c.AddNew();
```

however, this method didn't work with `List<DateTime>` even thouth List has Add method: CanAddNew was false. Maybe it is explained by the fact, that DateTime is an immutable structure.

This method seems limited, I would try another:

Not any IEnumerable has `Add` method, which defined in IList interface. If ItemsSource is not IList, then nothing can be added without special knowledge about concrete type. And even with IList addition is not guaranted (it can be ReadOnly or FixedSize (arrays, `[]`))

```
var c = ItemsSource as IList;
if (c != null && !c.IsReadOnly && !c.IsFixedSize)
    c.Add(newInstance);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay; Life took me away from work for a bit. This was extremely helpful, especially the link to the datagrid.cs code.Thank you for the information